# Adding an arrow in a googleVis bubble chart

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis, bubble-chart

I have the following plot:

[image: googleVis bubble chart]

I have a requirement to add an arrow from the Old Value to the new Value.
Is there any way i can add an arrow in a bubble chart or is there a way i can superimpose an arrow onto the bubble chart like we can do in ggplot

Code for my gvis bubble chart :

```
bub <- gvisBubbleChart(
            ttt2, 
            idvar = "ID",
            xvar = "x", yvar = "y",
            colorvar = "color",sizevar = "size",
            options = list(
              width = 700, height = 500,bubble.textStyle = '{fontSize : 1}',
              vAxis = "{title:'Low Risk Region...................High Risk Region'}",
              colors="['#FE642E','#58FA82', '#819FF7','#FF0000']"
            )
          )
```

Sample Data :

```
ID         x           y           size             color
Old     -1.350066    0.5388228   0.0010000000     Old Value
New      1.484894   -0.9232860   0.0010000000     New Value
ID       8.214781   -2.1834316   0.0006972322     Anchors
Gender  -1.113282   -8.4267789   0.0006934892     Anchors
Age     -2.033840    8.2530900   0.0010829137     Vital Anchors
BMI     -0.688272   -8.4720884   0.0004575001     Vital Anchors
```

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example (code you used, dataset) so it is easier to help.

Comment: I have updated my post. Would appreciate your help